# Function called when user stop typing on keyboard

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Imagine that I typing on the keyboard, and I want to call the function when user stop typing on keyboard. I don't want call the function each time when user push a keyboard button because my function calculate sth and my browser is freeze.

It is possible in Angularjs eg.

User start typing on keyboard and if user don't push the button by 2 seconds my function will be called ?

```
$scope.$watchCollection('collection', function(items) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        showData(items);;
        $scope.$apply();
    }, 1500);
});
```

I tried above code but this function will be called each time after 1500 ms.

Comment: There's no way to know when the user stops typing, but you can guesstimate that the user will find the next key within, say half a second, and if the user uses longer, he/she probably stopped typing.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions, specifically the part about debounce. Debounce causes the model change event related functions to fire after a set delay.

Comment: I want to use this grid https://github.com/MoonStorm/trNgGrid and what I type sth and I immediately get response, but when I apply debounce feature feature I will be waiting for grid filtering. I want to call my function after filtering.